# Gantt Chart in SiSense

Tags: sisense

I am little surprised there is no Gantt Chart available in SiSense (off the shelf). I understand there is a plugin available, but we were not able to integrate that. I believe it has something to do with the version / OS. We are currently on SiSense version 8.1.1.11011 and on Windows OS.
Plugin: [Gantt Chart | Sisense](https://www.sisense.com/marketplace/gantt-chart/)

We are trying to integrate the X Range High Chart but haven't had any success. Does anyone have any experience doing this? Please do share your experience

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

we have a Sisense Gantt control resdy to go for Sisense on Windows. Contact me via our website at [www.RapidBI.com.au](http://www.RapidBI.com.au).

@Moderators - not sure if commercial links are ok? I'm the cofounder of RapidBI, but in this instance, it only seems fair to help out?